# Trace-class norm and rank inequality

Tags: inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, trace

I am quite new to operators in Hilbert spaces and I have been trying to show that for any linear and bounded operator $T : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$
$$\|T\|_1 \leq \operatorname{rank}(T) \,\|T\|$$
where $\| T \|_1$ is the trace-norm of $T$, $\| T \|$ is its operator norm and $\operatorname{rank}(T)$ is the dimension of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

The idea is simple: the trace-norm is the sum of the eigenvalues of $T$, while the right part is the largest eigenvalue multiplied by the number of non-zero eigenvalues and so the inequality holds.

How can one prove this formally?

Comment: You should think of singular values, not eigenvalues

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should. Thanks!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I wondered about that; given what the OP said the definition was I assumed that was equivalent, at least for an operator of finite rank. Sorry, thanks...

Comment: "I think it is not formal enough since $||T||_1$ is actually not defined as the trace of $T$, but as the trace of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$". That doesn't say it's not formal enough, that says it's simply wrong. _As_ a proof that the sum of the eigenvalues satisfies that inequality it's certainly "formal enough". Never mind...